# java, saving input in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, input, save

for homework I am suppose to ask for the user to input his name 1 character at a time. Im using a for loop to keep asking him to input the next character. At the end I want to display the entire name, not just the last letter given. I know as the loop goes around it will keep printing out the last letter because `lastName=lastName.substring(0,1);`

How do I save that last letter entered and build a string with it? Thats my question

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class onecharacter {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    for(int x=1; x>-1; x++){
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner( System.in );

    String lastName;
    if (x==1){
    System.out.println ("Please enter your last name, one character at a time.");
    }
    else 
        {System.out.println ("Next letter");}
    lastName= userInput.nextLine();
    //System.out.println (lastName.substring(0,1));
    lastName=lastName.substring(0,1);// only reading first character in string. 
    //In case someone puts more than 1 character in.
    int answer=
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you finished?", "Click Yes or No:", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (answer== JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {System.out.println ("You entered " +lastName); 


                System.exit(0);}



                else if (answer== JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);

                else
                    System.out.println ("This is Impossible");


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce one more variable to read the line. Also using `StringBuilder` will be a good idea when you manipulate the string :

```
 StringBuilder lastName;
 String line;
    if (x==1){
    System.out.println ("Please enter your last name, one character at a time.");
    }
    else 
        {System.out.println ("Next letter");}
    line = userInput.nextLine();
    lastName.append(line.substring(0,1));
```

Modify your rest of the code if `StringBuilder` introduces some problem